# Multiple Context on the same device in opencl

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Can we have multiple contexts on the same device? If yes then is it concurrently available or is it parallel (at the same point of time)?

Comment: what is the difference between "concurrent" and "parallel" in your question?

Comment: Concurrent and parallel are different. Concurrent is TDM, while parallel means it is simultaneous; at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple  OpenCL Contexts on the same device.

Are really asking if you can create multiple context from within the same host process? I don't see any benefits for that configuration, as GPU utilization is controlled from the Command Queues and the order commands are submitted.

The device driver implementation  decides  how the Contexts are managed.   At present, GPU's are not multi-tasking, so Kernels are run as the Device driver decides, I expect first come first served. Roll on the Nvidia K20  ..